# How to set Default language other than english in Android?

Tags: android, localization, latin

I have a project by my client that has built successfully in his system but as he sent to me I am unable to compile it because of unicode characters (**Latin characters**) in default `strings.xml` under `res`. I believe its the default localizations file but its forcing me to convert it into English but not parsing Latin Characters into it.
e.g.

```
<string name="old_questions">Questões e soluções dos anos anteriores</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the XML is in UTF-8 and has

```
<?xml ... encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

or defaulted

```
 <?xml ... ?>
```

I tried your text in my studio , well it is working fine. You could also update question with your error , that would help understand it better.

Another workaround for small texts would be to simply escape it.

```
<string name="Example">Example character \u0026</string>
```

go to this website : https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character and this could help you .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your string file is in the default values folder.

You can check the android developers [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages) for better understanding.

To help you better please post the exact error you get while compiling the code.

Comment: yes theres only one res folder containing strings.xml which contains those latin strings